# Fast nearest neighbor search

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, similarity, knn

I have a table with ~3 millions rows. Each row represent an object with 5 properties. Each property value is float and in range from 0 to 1.

Table declared as

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  OBJECT_ID integer,
  property_1 float,
  property_2 float,
  property_3 float,
  property_4 float,
  property_5 float
);
```

I have to find first 10 most similar objects to specified one.

My query is:

```
select T2.OBJECT_ID,
       sqrt(
         (T1.property_1 - T2.property_1)^2 +
         (T1.property_2 - T2.property_2)^2 +
         (T1.property_3 - T2.property_3)^2 +
         (T1.property_4 - T2.property_4)^2 +
         (T1.property_5 - T2.property_5)^2
       ) similarity
  from tbl T1, tbl T2
 where T1.OBJECT_ID = 42
 order by 2
 limit 10;
```

How can I increase performance of search most similar objects?

Any solution is accepted (oracle, postgres, noSQL or C++).

Comment: Check out PostgreSQL's KNN searching. See e.g. http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/talks/pgcon-2010-1.pdf . I'd really need sample data to produce an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Doing fast KNN searching requires being able to do this off an index.  Doing so off a custom type as you have requires specifying whole ranges of indexing support for that table, and writing functions to accomplish the calculations.  So you are in for a lot of work and the answer isn't simple.

What you are going to have to do is, basically:

1. Review the GIST operators supported.
2. Write functions to support calculating any or all of these.
3. Create an operator class which ties these into a GIST index, and finally
4. Index your whole table using that index method.  If your table has big fields, you may have a problem (table inheritance here can help you out but that is another big topic).

Each of these would be plenty broad for a series of questions in its own right, so I don't think you can expect a solution here.  But that should give you a basic roadmap.